# Using Couchbase SDK in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to map the result of a couchbase query to a java reference type, so far I have found no way to do this. 
How can I capture the following as a java reference type:

```
N1qlQueryResult result = couchbaseBucket.query(
            N1qlQuery.simple("SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 1"));

JsonObject cust = result.allRows().get(0).value();
```

How can I cast this 'cust' to a java object? What would be the best way of doing this, doesnt the couchbase SDK provide some solution to this?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There was a [blog post published yesterday](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/) that shows you how to do this with couchbase spring-boot and spring data.

I'm not a Java expert at all, but it looks like you start by creating an entity class like this:

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Building {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String companyId;

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Then, create a repository class.

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "building")
public interface BuildingRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Building, String> {

    List<Building> findByCompanyId(String companyId);

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Finally, you can use `@Autowired` in a service class or wherever to instantiate a `BuildingRepository` and start calling the methods on it. [The full documentation for Spring Data Couchbase is available on docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)